# How can I make a efficient query to get all sorted by LastPostedDate threads from more than one group?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, aws-appsync, single-table-inheritance

I am using Single Table in DynamoDB and `Group` and `Thread` are stored in one table. One-to-many-relation. All threads are sorted by `lastPostedAt`. `lastPostedAt` is updated if a new comment or a new suggestion is posted in `Thread`. PK=Group#{id} SK=Thread#{id}. it is no problem to get all threads in a group. GIS PK=GroupID SK=Thread#lastPostedAt

Access Pattern:
Get all threads from more than one group. all threads are sorted by `lastPostedAt`.

How should I model for that access pattern with GIS?

Is it ok with large partitation key and Filterexpression?
GIS PK=Thread (without id) SK=lastPostedAt  Filterexpression=GroupID In ('Group1','Group2','Group3')

With filter expression, there can be difficulties in pagination if 'Group4' has a large number of elements compared to 'Group1', 'Group2' and 'Group3'.

If a group has a much larger number of elements than the other groups, this can lead to imbalances in pagination. If, for example, 'Group4' contains 1000 elements and 'Group1', 'Group2' and 'Group3' contain only 100 elements, it can be difficult to achieve a even distribution of the pagination across all groups.

schema.graphql

```
type Group
{
    id: ID!
    users: [User]
    admins: [User]
    title: String
}
type Thread
{
    id: ID!
    groupId: ID!
    term: String
    owner: user
    lastPostedAt: AWSDateTime
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the right answer here is that DynamoDB is not a good choice for this use case. Consider using a different DB technology or a secondary storage that builds your sorted view.

That being said, using a static hash key “Thread” is a possible option but would introduce scaling limits, as a single partition in DybamoDB can generally support only up to 3000 RSU and 1000 WSU per second. If you are sure that you’ll never hit that limit then go ahead.

Keep in mind that filtering on groups will not reduce amount of records that will be processed by DynamoDB during query. It only impacts returned result, but you will still be charged for all records (and performance will also suffer)

Answer (score 0):

#### Option 1

Use `GroupId` as the GSI partition key and `lastPostedAt` as sort key. Make multiple requests for each group you need, sorting the results on the client side.

#### Option 2

Use a global sort order. Define a static value as partition key, and `lastPostedAt` as sort key. This will order all the items in the table by `lastPostedAt` but means you would filter on group's that you need.

| gsipk | lastPostedAt | group |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2023-07-01T00:00:000 | 1 |
| 1 | 2023-07-01T01:00:000 | 4 |
| 1 | 2023-07-01T02:00:000 | 5 |
| 1 | 2023-07-01T03:00:000 | 1 |
| 1 | 2023-07-02T00:00:000 | 4 |
| 1 | 2023-07-02T11:00:000 | 7 |

Comment: Option 2 is not suitable. For small collection is Option 1 ok, but for large collection is not ok. I think I have to use secondary storage for sorted view.

Comment: Option 1 is fine even at scale. If you need 3 groups, you fire off 3 Query operations, one for each group. You can also limit the data to N number of items for each group.